# Does select * impact stored procedure performance?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I know this could be a trivial question but I keep hearing one of my teachers voice saying

> don't use SELECT * within a stored procedure, that affects performance and it's returning data that could be braking its clients if it's schema changes causing unknown ripple

I can't find any article confirming that concept, and I think that should be noticeable if true.

Comment: I don't know of any article either, but consider this - you do `SELECT *` in a procedure and fetch all columns, most of which you don't need and consume an extra bit of memory. Later, a binary BLOB column is added to the table to store some large binary data. Now your `SELECT *` also retrieving that blob unnecessarily, and consuming *lots more* memory. That's the ripple effect.  Be explicit about the columns you need. It makes code easier to understand, even if you have to type a little more.

Comment: Another possibility is the retrieval of columns which should never be visible to end users. If your application code changes the way it uses columns from the procedure, to display all cols in loop for example, rather than explicitly naming them, suddenly you may display sensitive data to end users.

Comment: Returning data that could break clients after schema changes is also a very real danger. Never use `SELECT *` in production code, only for one-off queries and debugging.

Comment: Thanks guys for confirming this, it is really important to be clear on these concepts and as it was not clearly stated anywhere I looked into I started to get worried about it's validity.

Comment: It's hard to figure out if this question is a good fit for Stack Overflow or a better fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com/.  The question still involves code, so I think it should stay here, it's not a question so much about database administration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most modern professional SQL implementations (Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, etc.), the use of `SELECT *` has a negative impact ***only*** in a top-level SELECT.  In all other cases the SQL compiler should perform column-optimization anyway, eliminating any columns that are not used.

And the negative effect of `*` in a top-level `SELECT` is almost entirely related to returning all of the columns when you probably do not *need* all of them.

IMHO, in all other cases(**), including most ad-hoc cases, the use of `*` is perfectly fine and has no determimental effects (and obvious beneficial conveniences).  The widespread universal pronouncements agaist using `*` are largely an archiac holdover from the time (10-15 years ago) when most SQL compilers did *not* have effective column-elimination optimization techniques.

(** - one exception is in `VIEW` definitions in SQL Server, because it doesn't automatically notice if the bound column list changes.)

---

The other reason that you sometimes see for not using `SELECT *` is not because of any performance issue, but just as a matter of coding practices.  That is, that it's generally better to write your SQL code to be *explicit* about what columns you (or your client code) expects and thus are dependent on.  If you use `*` then it's *implicit* and someone reading your SQL code cannot easily tell if your application is truly dependent on a certain column or not.  (And IMHO, this is the more valid reason.)

Answer (score 0):

I found this quote in a paper when we use SELECT * instruction:

“[…] real harm occurs when a sort is required. Every SELECTed column, with the sorting columns repeated, makes up the width of the sort work file wider. The wider and longer the file, the slower the sort is.” In http://www.quest.com/whitepapers/10_SQL_Tips.pdf

This paper is form DB2 engine but likely this is applied for other engines too.